# Change value of text field based on value in another text field in same row

Tags: jquery, yii

I am using Yii CGridView that has text field as cells. I have used CHtml::textField to display the text field. Now I want to update a cell in the grid on change of value in another cell in the same row. ID of text fields in same row has a common number. For example ProjectMBookGrid_length_163 and ProjectMBookGrid_quantity_163. On change of ProjectMBookGrid_length_163 value I want to change the value in ProjectMBookGrid_quantity_163, On change of ProjectMBookGrid_length_164 value I want to change the value in ProjectMBookGrid_quantity_164.
 JS Fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/7ykdkgaw/

```
<table>
    <tr><td><input type="text" id="ProjectMBookGrid_length_163" name="ProjectMBookGrid[length_163]" value="5" style="text-align: right" class="gridfield"></td><td><input type="text" id="ProjectMBookGrid_quantity_163" name="ProjectMBookGrid[quantity_163]" value="3" style="text-align: right" class="gridfield"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="text" id="ProjectMBookGrid_length_162" name="ProjectMBookGrid[length_162]" value="3" style="text-align: right" class="gridfield"></td><td><input type="text" id="ProjectMBookGrid_quantity_162" name="ProjectMBookGrid[quantity_162]" value="3" style="text-align: right" class="gridfield"></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: please make a fiddle

Comment: @P.Frank       Added JS Fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at updated fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/7ykdkgaw/2/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("change","input[id^=ProjectMBookGrid_length_]",
        function(){
            var currentVal = $(this).val();
            var currentId = $(this).attr("id");
            var numberInID = currentId.replace("ProjectMBookGrid_length_","");

            var targetText = $("#ProjectMBookGrid_quantity_"+numberInID);
            targetText.val(currentVal);
        });

});
```

Comment: It should not depend on "tr" or other table elements. Is it possible by text field class and id?